# Why to group list of object by an Id works only at first call in that function?

Tags: java, arraylist, group-by, sum

I want to group a list of objects (from a DB) by one if its elements, which works fine with the following this simplified code:

```
List<MyClass> sqlResultList;
List<MyClass> resultList;

public void applyMerge() {

    Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> map = 
            sqlResultList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyClass::getIdItem));

    resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer IdItem : map.keySet()) {

        List<MyClass> tmp = map.get(IdItem);

        if (tmp.size() > 0) {  

            MyClass head = tmp.get(0); // seems to create just a reference

        for (int i = 1; i < tmp.size(); i++) {

                MyClass obj = tmp.get(i);
                head.setMinutes(head.getMinutes() + obj.getMinutes());

            }

            resultList.add(head);

        } 
    }
}
```

**The only issue I have**, is that if I recall `applyMerge()` function it adds all values on top of previous sum value. I thought that the object `MyClass head` is just a temporary one, but it seems to be a reference `tmp` and the `map`.

Any hint what is my misconception here?

*ps: I can renew `sqlResultList` from the DB, but this I wanted to avoid, as the data itself didn't change.*

Comment: Not the downvoter, but there's a reason they're called *reference types*.

Comment: @shmosel and what is the correct approach in this case?

Comment: Approach to what? You've barely explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: I guess that's was the other down vote for, my bad. I want to sum different integer depending on the map I created. In the example I just sum `MyClass minutes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `head` object is a reference to the object in the original list. It is not a copy, so any modifications that you make to that object will also be seen by any other references to that object.

You will want to *clone* the object instead:

```
MyClass head = tmp.get(0).clone();
```

Methods of cloning vary, but the typical way is to override the `Object#clone()` method. In this method you will create a new instance of `MyClass` and then copy all of the properties you would like. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int minutes;

    public MyClass clone() {
        MyClass clonedInstance = new MyClass();
        clonedInstance.setMinutes(getMinutes());
        return clonedInstance;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return this.minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }
}
```

If you have other properties then you will want to make sure you are aware of any *deep* cloning that is necessary, too. For example, if you have a property that is a mutable type (such as as `List`) then you may want to clone that property, and on and on.

Many standard JDK types do provide their own `clone` methods as well, such as `ArrayList`.